# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer wrong orientation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have weird problem. I am recording a video in my app. Everything works fine until I rotate the device 180 degrees. It does not matter in which landscape mode I am starting the game the video starts correctly but once I rotate for example from landscape left to righ the video starts to record vertically. I made a draw to show: 
[image]

I am trying to set the video orientation like that: 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Left");
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    return YES;
}
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Right");
   captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

}
But this seems not working at all. I set the captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame=self.view.bounds; 
Still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct, except I'm not sure about the orientation you took. I think it should be

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Here is the full method you could try by invoking it from `shouldAutorotate` method:

```
- (void)autoRotateVideoOrientation {
     UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
     switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
           captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
           break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
          captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
          break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
          captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
          break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
          captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
          break;
        default:
          break;
   }
}
```

Comment: `statusBarOrientation` is deprecated as of iOS 9.0.